# Linux Runlevel 1: start programm

Tags: linux, debian, runlevel

I'm trying to automatically start a process when I enter runlevel `1` by `init 1`. It's a watchdog which has to send a life signal all the time therefore in runlevel `1` too! But when runlevel `1` is entered each process is killed and the system switches to runlevel `S`. I tried to tell linux to start my process by `update-rc.d -f watchdog 99 1 S .`. The resulting entries in `/etc/rc1.d/` and `/etc/rcS.d/` are:

`/etc/rc1.d/`:

```
.
.
.
S30killprocs -> ../init.d/killprocs
S90single -> ../init.d/single
S99watchdog -> ../init.d/watchdog
.
.
.
```

`/etc/rcS.d/`:

```
.
.
.
S01glibc.sh -> ../init.d/glibc.sh
S02hostname.sh -> ../init.d/hostname.sh
S99watchdog -> ../init.d/watchdog
.
.
.
```

A `ps ax` after runlevel `1` was entered sadfully doesn't return my watchdog process. I have to start it manually.

```
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:00 init [S]
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
    4 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:0]
    5 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u:0]
    6 ?        S      0:00 [rcu_kthread]
    7 ?        S<     0:00 [khelper]
    8 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u:1]
  104 ?        S      0:00 [sync_supers]
  106 ?        S      0:00 [bdi-default]
  108 ?        S<     0:00 [kblockd]
  119 ?        S      0:00 [khubd]
  219 ?        S      0:00 [kswapd0]
  220 ?        S      0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
  221 ?        S<     0:00 [aio]
  314 ?        S<     0:00 [scsi_tgtd]
  347 ?        S<     0:00 [kpsmoused]
  349 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:1]
  366 ?        S      0:00 [w1_bus_master1]
  390 ?        S      0:00 [mmcqd/0]
  395 ?        S      0:00 [jbd2/mmcblk0p2-]
  396 ?        S<     0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
  475 ?        S      0:00 [flush-179:0]
 4532 ttyS0    Ss     0:00 init [S]
 4533 ttyS0    S      0:00 bash
 4536 ttyS0    R+     0:00 ps ax
```

The system I'm working on is `Debian GNU/Linux 5.0 debarm` (embedded). Any hints or solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding following line into `/etc/inittab`:

```
~~:S:wait:/etc/init.d/watchdog start
~~:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin
```

Note: It must be before `/sbin/sulogin`.

Answer (score 2):

As said [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/212):

> Run Level 1 is known as 'single user' mode. A more apt description
>   would be 'rescue', or 'trouble-shooting' mode. In run level 1, **no
>   daemons (services) are started**.

You have several options to get around this limitation:

1. Don't use runlevel 1, this is not what it is meant for
2. Start the watchdog on login (if this is a valid option), e.g. `.bashrc`.

Comment: So is there a way to start it anyway? The watchdog process is an important one because if the hardware watchdog doesn't recognize any life signal, it performs a hardware reset.

Comment: Edited my question to add alternatives.

Comment: @Satish RedHat is not Debian, in fact they handle runlevels differently because (IIRC) RH is based on System V runlevels while Debian is based on BSD runlevels.

Comment: Option 1 is not an option. Neither option 2 is because i need it running on login prompt not when I logged in.

Comment: You didn't specify why option 1 is not option.